# изменение значений в config python telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

пишу бота на python telebot.
появилась проблема в следующем:
нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку бот изменял значение `server` на то которое пользователь введет
вот код записи

```
def get_new_server(message):
    sql.execute(f"SELECT status FROM users WHERE id='{message.chat.id}'")
    if sql.fetchall()[0][0] == 1 or 2:
        try:
            newserv = message.text
            config.server = newserv
            print(config.server)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Успешно изменено!')
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Похоже тебя нет в нашем боте.. Пропиши /start')
```

значение меняется, в боте это показывает, но если открыть config.py то там ничего не изменилось, также после перезапуска показывается старое значение. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что ты просто изменил значение в переменной в данной сессии, но никак не изменил по сути строчку кода, для таких случаев храни подобные значения в файлах конфигурации которые ты можешь в любой момент перезаписать
Так же совет, никогда не используй f строку для формирования sql запросов, такие запросы подвержены sql injection

Comment: хорошо, буду знать. Но я все равно не понял как мне сохранить измененное значение, именно по нажатию на кнопку

Comment: Выносишь данное значение в какой-нибудь конфигурационный файд, например json, пишишь функцию, которая при запуске бота будет считывать его в словарь, и когда тебе надо изменить значение, то меняешь в этом словаре, а так же открываешь файл и перезаписываешь там